# How to choose a kernel function for Gaussian process regression in a multivaritate settings?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, hierarchical-bayesian

Could you please suggest some lectures, books, or videos on how to choose a kernel function for Gaussian process regression in a multivaritate setting?

Answer (score 3):

David Duvenaud's [kernel cookbook](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~duvenaud/cookbook/) was a good starting place for me. His thesis, which is also linked on the webpage, is also an excellent resource.